# Bell pepper plant - brown (burnt/disease) new leaf growth: possible causes and remedies?

Tags: plant-health, diseases, leaves, peppers, bell-peppers

Complete beginner here, started learning how to grow pepper plants (and other type of plants) from seeds this year, so bare with me.

I am growing some bell pepper plants that I started from seeds which I took from a red pepper I bought early this year. All growing well, but I have one issue that is happening around all the plants (and often around other pepper varieties am growing like cayenne, thai chili):

**The plants grow well and healthy until they start to flower ie all the new leaf growth around the flowers turn brown and dry, and look like if a disease hit the plants or something else that I do not understand with my limited expertise.**

Here are some snapshots from two different plants (I circled in yellow the brown/burnt leaves)
[image: pepper-plant-issue-1]

[image: pepper-plant-issue-2]

[image: pepper-plant-issue-3]

[image: pepper-plant-issue-4]

What are possible causes for this? and what should I do to fix it (if any issues)?